# align image in a div vertically center

Tags: html, css

**CODE:**

```
.company-logo-wrap{
    display: block;
    background: #fff;
    margin-left: -15px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #a5a5a5;
    text-align: center;
    height: 400px;
}
```

---

Tried inline block, float etc, couldn't get it work..
I cannot use padding / margin as it's user upload img, so the size is not always the same.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Hbjga/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`vertical-align: middle`** property, which will work only with `display: table-cell/table`

```
.company-logo-wrap{
    display: table-cell;  
    background: #fff;
    margin-left: -15px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #a5a5a5;
    text-align: center;
    height: 400px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hbjga/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:table` and `table-cell`

```
.company-logo-wrap{
    display:table; 
    background: #fff;
    margin-left: -15px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
    height: 400px;
    width:100%
}
.company-logo-inner{
  display:table-cell;
   vertical-align:middle;
  background:grey
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/adiyataQ/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use following Css

```
.company-logo-wrap{
    display: table;
    background: #fff;
    margin-left: -15px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #a5a5a5;
    text-align: center;
    height: 400px;
    width:100%

}

.company-logo-inner {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="main">

 <div class="box"></div>   
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main{ height:500px; border:1px red solid;position:relative}
.box{width:40px; height:40px; background:red; }

/* for centering */
.box{ display: inline-block; }
.main{ text-align: center; }
.main:after{ content: ""; display: inline-block; height: 100%; vertical-align: middle; }
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/SxxWV/11/